# DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script does not have a MIME type

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

It is my first time to use service worker. I got an error "The script does not have a MIME type.". Can anyone help with this issue?

> The script does not have a MIME type.
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
>
> Service worker registration failed: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The script does not have a MIME type.
>   register.js:6

**register.js**

```js
// Make sure sw are supported
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw_cached_page.js').then(function(registration) {
        console.log('Service Worker: Registered (Pages)');
    },function(error){
        console.log('Service worker registration failed:', error);
    });
}else{
    console.log('Service workers are not supported.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like your browser couldn't load the file sw_cached_page.js correctly. Check in chrome devtools what your browser actually downloaded.

Check the content-type:

[image: Check the content-type]

And check the content:

[image: check the actual content]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found nothing in Preview and Response tab on Chrome DevTools. "Provisional headers are shown" shown in Request Headers from the Headers tab.

Answer (score 0):

Please inlcude service worker js file in your html file

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myproject/scripts/common/pushNotifications/sw.js"></script>
```

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/mproject/scripts/common/pushNotifications/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
  console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.active);
});
```